# Why google play services lib error occurring while uploading logcat file

Tags: google-play-services

Can anyone please tell me why that Google Play services lib error is occurring. This is my logcat file:

```
01-20 19:11:56.505: D/dalvikvm(32169): open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-2.apk@classes.dex
01-20 19:11:56.526: D/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs_liteMode
01-20 19:11:56.526: W/dalvikvm(32169): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1484 (MapAttrs_liteMode) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
01-20 19:11:56.526: D/dalvikvm(32169): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x00af
01-20 19:11:56.527: D/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs_liteMode
01-20 19:11:56.527: I/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x05cc at 0xb7 in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;.createFromAttributes
01-20 19:11:56.527: D/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs_uiMapToolbar
01-20 19:11:56.527: I/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x05cf at 0xc0 in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;.createFromAttributes
01-20 19:11:56.527: D/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs_uiMapToolbar
01-20 19:11:56.527: I/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x05cf at 0xc8 in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;.createFromAttributes
01-20 19:11:56.527: D/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs_ambientEnabled
01-20 19:11:56.527: I/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x05c6 at 0xd1 in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;.createFromAttributes
01-20 19:11:56.527: D/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs_ambientEnabled
01-20 19:11:56.527: I/dalvikvm(32169): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x05c6 at 0xd9 in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;.createFromAttributes
01-20 19:11:56.527: D/AndroidRuntime(32169): Shutting down VM
01-20 19:11:56.527: W/dalvikvm(32169): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414299a8)
01-20 19:11:56.527: E/test(32169): Exception
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable.MapAttrs_liteMode
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4794)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:280)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1899)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-20 19:11:56.530: E/AndroidRuntime(32169):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Comment: May I know what version of Google Play Services you are using and can you give more details regarding the error logs?

Comment: this is the version which i used in my app                                           <integer name="google_play_services_version">8487000</integer>              and the complete logcat is above which i already provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating your Google Repository to version 15 via the SDK Manager should resolve the issues and eliminate the needs for the workarounds. A project clean is required.

Android SDK

This is also mentioned in [issue 7432](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7432).